# Optimization of Quadratic Equation with Wirtinger Calculus

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, partial-derivative, quadratics, cubics

The problem is to find the complex-valued solution $z$ of the real-valued cost function $f(z)$:

$$z^* = \mathop{argmin}_\limits{z\in \mathbb{C}} (f- |z|^2)^2 + \alpha|z-d|^2,$$
where $f, \alpha \in \mathbb{R+}$ and $d \in \mathbb{C}$ are some constants.

The natural idea is to find the stationary point of this formula. So I try to use Wirtinger calculus, the $f(z)$  can be expressed as: $f(z,\bar{z}) = (f^2 - 2fz\bar{z} + z^2\bar{z}^2) + \alpha \overline{(z-d)}(z-d)$.

Then, the derivative is: 
$$\frac{\partial f(z,\bar{z})}{\partial z} = (2z\bar{z}^2-2f\bar{z}) + \alpha (\bar{z} - \bar{d}) = 0.$$

Therefore, the derivative involves $z$ and $\bar{z}$. I dont know how to find the $z^*$ since $\bar{z}$ is also unknown for me. Is there any suggestion? Or is it a correct way to find the solution? Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: change the objective function

Comment: It's fairly easy to just write $z=x+yi$ and convert your cost function into a real function of the two real variables $x$ and $y$.  Then you can set the gradient of this real function of two real variables to zero (a system of two equations in the two unknowns $x$ and $y$) to find the minimum.  Or do you really want to use Wirtinger calculus?

Comment: Although I can split the $z$ into  $x$ and $y$. But this is a bit "burte force". So is there any method to use Wirtinger calculus?

Comment: @J.Heller Forget @ you